# Monitoring database changes without using 'SqlDependency' class

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008

I'm currently using Microsoft SQL Server 2008.

My production server has a very heavy load.

My C# application uses 'SqlDependency' class in order to monitor some table changes.

On development environment - the application works fine, and the change events from the SQL server gets fired correctly.

On production environment - the application gets change events even when there wasn't any change. I have read that the 'SqlDependency' doesn't perform well on heavy load.

I'm looking for other solution to this scenario, any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you get notified when there is no change it means something else triggered the notification. You **must** always inspect the [`SqlNotificationEventArgs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlnotificationeventargs.aspx) argument received on your `OnChange` handler and react appropriately based on the  [`Info`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlnotificationeventargs.info.aspx), [`Source`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlnotificationeventargs.source.aspx) and [`Type`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlnotificationeventargs.type.aspx). In production you very likely get a notification like [`Info.Options`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlnotificationinfo.aspx) signifying incorrect SET options (ie. an environment specific problem).

As for the comment about `SqlDependency` under load, you will have to link the source. But query notification overall is designed for cache invalidation of data that changes *seldom*.

Comment: Can I set the event would fire only when a some of "SqlNotification" condition will occure ?
For example: event will fire up when the Type is 'Subscribe' and Source is 'Statement'

Comment: The events fire because you have an incorrect setup. You can't fix your problem by simply declaring "I want to ignore my problem, make it magically work". **Fix the problem reported by the event**.

Comment: What do you mean by saying incorrect setup ?
For example: I'm getting SqlNotificationInfo of "Invalid".
How can I check what is the problem, or tell SQL not to raise the event when getting it ?

Comment: [`Invalid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlnotificationinfo.aspx): *A statement was provided that cannot be notified (for example, an UPDATE statement).*. You need to troubleshoot and investigate. Use the MSDN to clarify what the event args values mean. Read [Creating a Query for Notification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms181122.aspx) to understand what is valid and what not.

Comment: OK, I moved to production a version where I write to the event log. I'm getting Info of "Resource", which I've read in the API that: "Resource Fires as a result of server resource pressure. "
How can I tell SQL not to throw this kind of event ?